# Cannot load rsync daemon in Sierra. Log shows: "assertion failed: 16G1408: libxpc.dylib"

Tags: launchd, plist, rsync, daemons

I'm trying to start `rsync --daemon` on Sierra (10.12.6), using `launchctl`. It used to work fine (last time in Mavericks, I think). But now on Sierra, the daemon does not start and `grep rsync /var/log/system.log` only shows this:

```
... rsync[12201]: assertion failed: 16G1408: libxpc.dylib + 20887 [BF896DF0-D8E9-31A8-A4B3-01120BFEEE52]: 0xf
```

Googling this cryptic message didn't give me a clue either.

I do know about SIP, and have it disabled:

```
$ csrutil status
System Integrity Protection status: disabled.
```

The way I'm trying to configure my damon is by following [this guide](http://bahut.alma.ch/2013/01/rsync-server-daemon-on-mac-os-x.html), which consists basically of:

- creating `/etc/rsyncd.conf` and `rsyncd.secrets`
- creating `/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.samba.rsync.plist`
- loading the plist file with `launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.samba.rsync.plist`
- and starting it with `launchctl start org.samba.rsync`

The plist file does get loaded, but the daemon is not running:

```
$ launchctl list | grep rsync
-   0   org.samba.rsync
```

What could this `assertion failed: 16G1408: libxpc.dylib` message mean?

Has something changed in Sierra with how to start daemons?

Comment: Can you run r sync from the command line?

Comment: Yes, it does run from the command-line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, Sierra and possibly earlier versions as well, need the rsync daemon to be started with the `--no-detach` option, which wasn't needed before.

The error message `assertion failed: 16G1408: libxpc.dylib` that appeared in the logs when it didn't work remains a mystery. But this .plist file now works to solve the original problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Disabled</key>
    <false/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>org.samba.rsync</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/bin/rsync</string>
        <string>--daemon</string>
        <string>--no-detach</string> <!-- This is needed now -->
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <dict>
        <key>SuccessfulExit</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```